# How to send a SharedPreferences file via webservice to remote database

Tags: android, web-services, sharedpreferences, ksoap

I want to know the way by which I can send a SharedPreference file as a parameter to my SOAP web service. I plan to use ksoap. My SharedPreference file basically will contain checked values of checkbox that I plan to implement in one of the activities of my project.

On the server side, after I send the file over the web service I need to insert every checked value the file contains in a database column that I have made.

I also need to delete that file, once the task is accomplished since I do no plan to store any data on my phone.

Can anyone who has come across such a situation tell me how to go about implementing a code for this? I know how to do a SOAP web service call. I just need to know the way to send the SharedPreferences file and in what type are the contents stored in that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences#getAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29) to obtain a map of all the shared preferences, then put it in the web service in whatever format you like.

Comment: I read the link u gave, it says it returns a map that contains a list of key/value pairs. I really don't know what exactly is a Map ? So can u please tell me about it ? Also whenever I read this key/value pair, the first thing that comes to my mind is JSON. But really do u feel I can send the data in my SharedPreferences file as a parameter. Can u tell me in request.addPropery() method of ksoap how do I pass that file?

Comment: thanks for the link again !! I checked out the Map interface over there, saw an example where they created a Map "m" and in that small code they just print the content of "m" which is in this form: {to=3, delegate=1, be=1, it=2, up=1, if=1, me=1, is=2}. In my case, "m" will look something like this : {john,annie,jake} since I am checking the names, so then how will I send that to my web service because ksoap doesn't provide Object[] passing as of now. How do I get a String so as to pass it